# SQL WHILE statement error "The column prefix does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, while-loop, cumulative-sum

I am trying to run the below SQL statement and am getting  the below message

The column prefix 'timInvtTran' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Basically what I'm trying to do is to get the resulting Quantity on Hand (QOH) after each inventory transaction. 
An assumption to this is that when summing TranQty you will get the resulting QOH.
I am trying to loop the data and add a running total of TranQty, which would by definition be the QOH. I named my QOH variable as @currQOH .

I know the issue is coming from my SET statement but I can’t figure out why it’s happening.

As a side note, am I on the correct path to getting a running total of TranQty? I don’t want to write to the DB and so I don’t want to create new tables for my running total. I researched high and low and couldn’t find anything.

Any bit of help would be extremely appreciated.

```
DECLARE @currQOH INT
SET @currQOH=0

WHILE(  Select ItemKey  from timInvtTran) = 41511
BEGIN
    SET @currQOH = @currQOH + timInvtTran.TranQty
    BREAK

END

select @currQOH, ItemKey, TranID
from timInvtTran
where timInvtTran.ItemKey = 41511  and substring(tranid,12,2) <>'SH'
order by timinvttran.createdate desc
```

BTW Happy PI day!

Comment: While and Begin-End aren't SQL constructs.  They are vendor specific procedural extensions to SQL.  What RDBMS is this for?  It looks a bit like T-SQL.  Is this for SQL-Server?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning in my original post. I am using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: This link might prove useful if you want a running total http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/300785/Calculating-simple-running-totals-in-SQL-Server

Comment: This looks great, the only thing is I want to avoid using any other tables. The only option to not creating a new table to store data is to use SQL server 2012. Is there any way to do it using 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
DECLARE @currQOH INT
SET @currQOH= ( select sum(TranQty) from timInvtTran where ItemKey   = 41511 )

select @currQOH, ItemKey, TranID
from timInvtTran
where timInvtTran.ItemKey = 41511  and substring(tranid,12,2) <>'SH'
order by timInvttran.createdate desc
```

Note the case change in the last line: timinvttran -> timInvttran

Comment: Pieter thanks for the alternative way of writing this up - the issue is that for any given ItemKey there will be multiple. If I run a Sum(TranQty) then i will get the same currQOH for all transactions instead of a running total